# Loading Bar in table Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading

Hello here's my json :

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAAAAA",
        "loading": "False",
    },
    {
        "name": "BBBBBB",
        "loading": "45%",
    },
    {
        "name": "CCCCCC",
        "loading": "12%",
    },
    {
        "name": "DDDDDD",
        "loading": "False",
    }
]
```

My javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('names.json').then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.names = data.data;
            console.log($scope.names);
        }
    );
```

HTML :

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td>{{name.loading}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What i try to do is loading bar for name.loading %. I get it from server, and the % is loading for something, so it still load (ex. in first second 15%, in second 25%...), and when its 100% name.loading = "False". I need loading bar in the table name.loading, only when its %, when its "False", in table should be just "False". 
Thanks in advance

Comment: it is an anti-pattern to wrap `$http` inside a deferred, since `$http` already returns a promise.  that being said, what you are asking for here isn't something easily accomplished with `$http`, since it doesn't expose information on the individual packets of data.

Comment: reading the question again, it's not really even clear what this "loading bar" is supposed to represent.  are you trying to show more than one loading bar, for the status of something that is happening on the server for each row here? and if so, how often are you checking the server for updates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) in html5.

Edit your code like below.

```
<td><progress value="{{name.loading}}" max="100" ng-if="name.loading != 'False'">{{name.loading}} %</progress></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngIf` directive to achieve that.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td ng-if="name.loading !== 'False'">{{name.loading}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: yes but what is loading === 'False', and how to do loading bar?

Comment: @bafix2203 I understood that you need to display or hide the td where you show loading. But having this in mind you can use ng-if to show a component that represents your loading bar.

Comment: <td ng-if="name.loading !== 'False' ng-show='loading'">{{name.loading}}</td>